# Conditional namespaces in mvc views

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working on MVC 3 and using resource files to localize the application. Now we have another customer on board for the application and they would like to change some of the text on the application..typical.

I have create a separated resource file for them and would like to do something like this in views

if (customer =A )
@using Resources.customerA
else
@using Resources.customerB

I've a resource class in both namespaces so something like this works fine if I change the namespace

Resource.WelcomeUser

Is it possible to use conditional using statement in views? I'm unable to find the right syntax for this. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that class name for resource file is same for all customers. I've only created a different namespace for each class because most of the code has already been written and I would like to keep that code in views same and dont want to change it everywhere.

Here is how my code is structured.

namespaces resources.customerA
{
    class resource
    {
    }
}

namespaces resources.customerB
{
    class resource
    {
    }
}

Comment: I did it this way because in the views I already have syntax like 
Resource.WelcomeUser which I didn't want to change everywhere so I thought if I just change the namespace things would work, they actually work if I change the namespace at design time.

Answer (score 0):

You can put both using statements in View, but when you use classes you would have to write some namespace prefix. 
Example:

```
@using Project.Resources.customerA 
@using Project.Resources.customerB
```

using classes:

```
customerA.WelcomeUser
customerB.WelcomeUser
```

I think there is no other way, because two files cannot have the same path.

Answer (score 0):

What you're really talking about is the provider pattern. You have two (or more) interchangeable things, and you want to be able to use one or the other contextually.

The correct way to do this in an OO context is to create and use an interface, while then injecting the actual implementation you want at runtime. You can actually achieve this in ASP.NET Core, which supports injection in Views, but in ASP.NET MVC 5 and previous, you'd need to go a little out of your way. I'm imagining these are currently static classes, since you're referencing them merely via namespace. With that approach, you'd need to follow @Ssheverdin's advice and use the FQN of the class (i.e. with the namespace):

```
@if (customer == A)
{
    @Resources.customerA.StaticClass.Property
}
else
{
    @Resources.customerB.StaticClass.Property
}
```

Alternatively, you could change the static classes to be instance classes and use a factory pattern to return the right one. This is a very simplistic example, but hopefully enough to convey the idea:

```
public static class ResourceFactory
{
    public static IResourceClass GetForCustomer(string customer)
    {
        switch (customer)
        {
            case "A":
                return new Resources.customerA.ResourceClass();
            default:
                return new Resources.customerB.ResourceClass();
        }
    }
```

Then:

```
@{ var resource = ResourceFactory.GetForCustomer(customer); }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to achieve the behaviour by adding a web.config file under views folder and including the namespaces there, i have to remove the @using statement from all views obviously. You might find that intellisense doesn't work anymore for you so try closing all views and reopen them again.

With this way I can create a separate web.config file for each customer and specify the relevant namespaces accordingly. Now just have to make sure to provide the RIGHT config file for each customer when deploying the release:)